# Infinite loop when iterating through a vector?

Tags: loops, vector

I've been searching around, but am running into trouble. I'm not sure why, but this code runs into a loop and never ends.

```
int Library::patronCount()
{
    int result = 0;
    vector<Patron>::iterator iter;

    iter = vPatron.begin();

    while (iter != vPatron.end())
    {
        if(!(*iter).isDeleted)
        {
            result++;
        }
        iter;
    }
    return result;
```

}

Is there a better way to iterate through the vector `Patron`? I thought of using `vPatron.size()` but got an error saying `no operator "!=" match these operands`.

EDIT:

I literally forgot to add `++` to the `iter;` line. Thank you Beta.

Comment: Don't you mean `++iter;`?

Comment: Wow haha. That's exactly it. I can't believe I missed it. Thank you @Beta!